# How to load different Scss files with Meteor routed pages

Tags: javascript, meteor, sass, iron-router, file-structure

I'm creating a Meteor site routed with Iron Router. Every subpage has it's own folder and it's own `Scss` files. The problem is that all `Scss` files become available on every subpage after compiling.

It's easy to solve by adding `html class="homePage"` or `html class="adminPage"`, then prefix styling with `.adminPage {...code goes here...}`, but when it comes to Excluding a Big files, such entire `html5reset.scss`, prefixing all names is not a good solution. How to exclude `html5reset.scss` files from a particular routes?

```
file structure
/homepage
  > global.scss
  > homePage.scss
  > html5reset.scss

/404
  > global.scss
  > 404Page.scss
  > html5reset.scss

/admin
  > global.scss
  > adminPage.scss
  // NO HTML5 reset

/framework
  > global.scss
  > frameworkPage.scss
  // NO HTML5 reset
```

And this is how i dynamically set html classnames:

HTML

```
<template name="homePage">
  {{HTML_CLASS 'homePage'}}
</template>
```

CLIENT JS

```
// dynamically set html class
Handlebars.registerHelper( "HTML_CLASS", function ( htmlClass ){
  var root = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
  if (htmlClass) {
    root.setAttribute( "class", htmlClass );
  } else {
    alert("this page has not html class");
    root.setAttribute( "class", "otherPage" );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nicer way of putting classes on the html tag using iron-router:

[Css class in body with Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382531/css-class-in-body-with-meteor)

Excluding css in your client folder isn't possible, but there is a dirty way of achieving it by putting it in your public folder:

[Excluding bootstrap from specific routes in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685957/excluding-bootstrap-from-specific-routes-in-meteor)

Comment: Since I need to exclude only CSS reset this might be the solution ;). Registering page title as a helper allows me to define title in a template,  this is very useful.

Comment: According to Your suggestion I've used public folder for including route-specific css/js files and written a helper for it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30833068/3836715